# Is thermal disintegration of meteorites variable with lattitude?

Tags: planetary-atmosphere, meteorite

If meteorites and bolides are aligned to the solar system,  then do they have twice as much atmosphere to go through at high latitudes?

Wouldn't we expect a higher percentage of metal meteorites further from the equator,  because they disintegrate slower in prolonged atmospheric traversal?

Image from:
https://academic.oup.com/mnras/article/359/2/551/987238

http://www.skyandtelescope.com/observing/random-meteors-arent-random02112015/

[image]

Comment: That diagram is ok as far as it goes, but what about the inclination of the ecliptic? And I think we also need to consider bodies whose trajectories have been gravitationally deflected by Earth, either during the current encounter, or on previous passes.

Comment: Searching for graphs of trajectories of meteors leads me to very interesting galleries and websites.